# WP Audio Shortcode and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, wordpress

I want to use the function `wp_audio_shortcode()` via AJAX, then I want to customize the audio player style, but the problem is that the HTML code returned by the AJAX request does not allow me to customize the audio player style, because it's returning:

```
<audio class="wp-audio-shortcode" id="audio-0-1" preload="none" style="width: 100%;" controls="controls">
<source type="audio/ogg" src="my_url" />
<a href="my_url">my_url</a>
```

The returning HTML code  when I use AJAX is not the same as the code when I'm only using PHP. (Example Below).

How can I obtain the same result as PHP in AJAX?

1 - PHP Code

```
function wp_audio_player() {
    $ogg_file = "https://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/ogg/example.ogg";
    $attr = array(
        'src' => $ogg_file,
        'loop' => '',
        'autoplay' => '',
        'preload' => 'none'
    );
    return wp_audio_shortcode( $attr );
}
echo wp_audio_player();

// returning this html code:
<div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container mejs-container-keyboard-inactive wp-audio-shortcode mejs-audio" tabindex="0" role="application" aria-label="Lecteur audio" style="width: 1245px; height: 40px; min-width: 239px;">
  <div class="mejs-inner">
    <div class="mejs-mediaelement">
      <mediaelementwrapper id="audio-4208-1"><audio class="wp-audio-shortcode" id="audio-4208-1_html5" preload="none" style="width: 100%; visibility: visible; height: 100%;" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/ogg/example.ogg?_=1"><source type="audio/ogg" src="https://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/ogg/example.ogg?_=1"><a href="https://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/ogg/example.ogg">https://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/ogg/example.ogg</a></audio></mediaelementwrapper>
    </div>
    <div class="mejs-layers">
      <div class="mejs-poster mejs-layer" style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mejs-controls">
      <div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-play"><button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Lecture" aria-label="Lecture" tabindex="0"></button></div>
      <div class="mejs-time mejs-currenttime-container" role="timer" aria-live="off"><span class="mejs-currenttime">00:00</span></div>
      <div class="mejs-time-rail"><span class="mejs-time-total mejs-time-slider"><span class="mejs-time-buffering" style="display: none;"></span><span class="mejs-time-loaded"></span><span class="mejs-time-current"></span><span class="mejs-time-hovered no-hover"></span><span class="mejs-time-handle"><span class="mejs-time-handle-content"></span></span>
        <span
          class="mejs-time-float" style="display: none;"><span class="mejs-time-float-current">00:00</span><span class="mejs-time-float-corner"></span></span>
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="mejs-time mejs-duration-container"><span class="mejs-duration">00:00</span></div>
      <div class="mejs-button mejs-volume-button mejs-mute"><button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Muet" aria-label="Muet" tabindex="0"></button></div>
      <a class="mejs-horizontal-volume-slider" href="javascript:void(0);" aria-label="Curseur de volume" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" role="slider"><span class="mejs-offscreen">Utilisez les flèches haut/bas pour augmenter ou diminuer le volume.</span>
        <div class="mejs-horizontal-volume-total">
          <div class="mejs-horizontal-volume-current" style="left: 0px; width: 100%;"></div>
          <div class="mejs-horizontal-volume-handle" style="left: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2 - PHP & Ajax Code

```
// PHP
add_action('wp_ajax_wp_audio_player', 'wp_audio_player_ajax'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wp_audio_player', 'wp_audio_player_ajax');
function wp_audio_player_ajax() {
    $ogg_file = "https://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/ogg/example.ogg";
    $attr = array(
        'src'      => $ogg_file,
        'loop'     => '',
        'autoplay' => '',
        'preload'  => 'none'
    );
    echo wp_audio_shortcode( $attr );
    die();
}

// Javascript
jQuery.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : AJAX_URL,
    data : {
      action : 'wp_audio_player',
    },
    success:function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });

// returning  this html code:
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script>document.createElement('audio');</script><![endif]-->
<audio class="wp-audio-shortcode" id="audio-0-1" preload="none" style="width: 100%;" controls="controls">
    <source type="audio/ogg" src="https://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/ogg/example.ogg?_=1" />
    <a href="https://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/ogg/example.ogg">https://cdn.online-convert.com/example-file/audio/ogg/example.ogg</a>
</audio>
```

Comment: Where did you get the lines following '// returning this html code:'?

Comment: in the code source page

Comment: You can copy the code from the original `wp_audio_shortcode()` function and adapt/clean it to your neeeds. It's on `wp-includes/media.php` file

Comment: @brasofilo I don't think that will work because the real work is being done by JavaScript and not PHP. Mejs on the frontend is dynamically rewriting the DOM HTML media elements, so the relevant code does not exists in the backend. I think the problem is that processing is done on document ready and not done on later dynamically inject media elements.

Comment: @magenta, oh, yes, sure shot! The shortcode loads the script `'wp-mediaelement'`. <edit> Well, OP could do the dynamics after AJAX... but only testing the thing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is certainly because:

- Outputing the `wp_audio_player()` from ajax will only give the HTML markup
- I believe `wp_audio_player()` to also add scripts (css maybe) to the page when called normally, without ajax.

What you could try:

- Try to put another hidden `wp_audio_player()` in your PHP template to load the required scripts. It could work directly, or you could need to analyse the script to trigger what's needed.
- you may also be able to queue it as seen [here](https://blog.josemcastaneda.com/2016/11/13/wordpress-mediaelement-styles/) `wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-mediaelement' );`
- As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180840/wordpress-audio-using-wp-audio-shortcode) it's possible to prevent Wordpress to load [those scripts](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/tree/master/wp-includes/js/mediaelement) (some of them at least)

Audio Player:

- Why do you need the Wordpress one, and cannot use a typical HTML5 audio player ?

Comment: Mustapha Fersaoui can easily check if this is the problem by using his browser developer tools and verifying that the JavaScript file mediaelement.js has been loaded. It has been a while since I worked with mejs but I think the problem will turn out to be something different - mejs actually rewrites the player DOM elements. Unfortunately, it only does this when the HTML document is initially loaded so later dynamically inserted players are not processed. I know there is a workaround but I need to see the source code which is not on the machine I am using now.

Comment: That's what I thought. I tried several methods, but were not successful.
If I don't find any solution i will probably use an HTML5 audio player pending a solution. and i will be happy if you check your source code for me :).

Comment: Studying the JS code should permit to find the good function to call. As the original script certainly does it 'onDocumentReady', you "just" need to call the same method in your script.

Comment: Probably the code in ...\wp-includes\js\mediaelement\wp-mediaelement.js - I am too busy and lazy to actually test this so if you want to do it I will add my 10 points to any that Mustapha Fersaoui gives you.

Comment: See - $('.wp-audio-shortcode,.wp-video-shortcode').not('.mejs-container').filter(function(){return ! $(this).parent().hasClass('mejs-mediaelement';}).mediaelementplayer( settings ); - near the bottom.

Comment: I found that but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: After you received HTML from ajax, append it to your dom. 
As @magenta found out, find in the `settings` variable, duplicate it in your script, and call `.mediaelementplayer( settings );` on your newly append element.
If your custom script is included in the DOM before the media script, it'll fail. In this case, use a higher priority number for your enqueue.

Comment: I think it is easier than that just do window.wp.mediaelement.initialize(); after inserting the media element into the DOM. initialize() is written in a way that calling it again probably does no harm except for wasting CPU cycles by re-creating settings when it was already created.

Comment: solution is:  1- enqueue MediaElement styles and script : wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-mediaelement' );
wp_enqueue_script('wp-mediaelement'); 2- add : window.wp.mediaelement.initialize(); after inserting the media element.